# To calculate the image of a rational map.

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f:\mathbb{P}^n\dashrightarrow\mathbb{P}^N$ be a rational map over $\mathbb{C}$, defined by a  linear system $\subseteq |\mathcal{O}(d)|$ without fixed component , $Y:=\overline{f(\mathbb{P}^n)}\subseteq\mathbb{P}^N$. Using software such as Macaulay2, Sage,... it is easy to calculate $H^0(\mathbb{P}^N, I_{Y,\mathbb{P}^N}(t))$ for each $t\geq 1$, but I'm interested in the ideal $I=\oplus_{t= 1}^{\infty}H^0(\mathbb{P}^N,I_{Y,\mathbb{P}^N}(t))$. Until what $t$ I have to calculate $H^0(\mathbb{P}^N,I_{Y,\mathbb{P}^N}(t))$ to make sure I have found all generators of the ideal $I$?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason to avoid just using Groebner bases to find equations for the image, rather than finding the global sections of the twisted ideal?

Comment: I do not know other ways to determine the image of f! Using Groebner bases, how should I proceed, for example, on macaulay2? – gio 0 secs ago

Comment: Your map of projective spaces corresponds to a map of their homogeneous coordinate rings, in the opposite direction.  The kernel of this map is the ideal you are looking for, and Macaulay can calculate it (usually without much difficulty for small enough n, N).